# SharePoint JSON Conditional Formatting in a Form

Tags: json, sharepoint, conditional-statements, sharepoint-online

I am using the new JSON configure layout option in SharePoint Online on a List Form. The show/hide logic works great. However, I need to combine two if statements and am having issues. Separately they look like this:

`=if([$RequestStatus] == 'New Request', 'false', 'true')`

`=if(indexOf([$RequestDescription],'LSTeam')<0, 'false', 'true')`

I need to combine them with an OR statement or something similar. I found this but it doesn't work:

`=if([$RequestStatus]=='New Request','false',if(indexOf([$RequestDescription],'LSTeam')<0,'false','true'))`

I also tried:

`=if([$RequestStatus]=='New Request' || indexOf([$RequestDescription],'LSTeam')<0,'false','true'))`

Is there anything else I can try?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Asp per my test, it works well in my list:

```
=if([$RequestStatus]=='New Request','false',if(indexOf([$RequestDescription],'LSTeam')<0,'false','true'))
```

[image]

What's wrong with this formula in your scenario?

Comment: the first condition should hide it until the status changes to anything else. the second condition makes the field available once the keyword is placed in the description field. Request Description is a multi line text field and Request Status should be a choice field. For me the field fails to appear under both conditions. Only when i add them individually does it work. I will try again on a fresh list.

Comment: Tested on a fresh list and ran into same problem. Used together they fail to work. The field that should be appearing stays hidden even when the status changes and even if the keyword is typed into the description field. I’m close though, please help!